Error of Access-Control-Allow-Origin for post request with data
I try to create a post ajax request with data using Axios when the server side is ASP classic and the client side is React using type script
this is my server side :
<% Response.AddHeader "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*" %>
<% Response.AddHeader "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS" %>
<% Response.AddHeader "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization" %>



<%
    Response.Write("hed")

%>

this is my simple client side :
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {loginResult} from './models/loginResult.ts'
const Login: React.FC = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');

  const handleLogin = async () => {
    try {
        //const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:12403/login.asp');


        const dataToSend = {
            username: username,
        };
        const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:12403/login.asp',dataToSend);
        console.log(response.data);
        
        //var d = new loginResult();
        //d = JSON.parse(response.data);
        //console.log(d);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } finally {

    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Username"
        value={username}
        onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
      />
    
      <button onClick={handleLogin}>Login</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;

my index.tsx :
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import Login from './Login.tsx';
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Login />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

this is what I get for my request :

when I try it without of data as :  const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:12403/login.asp'); its work fine
like that :


You need to add in your server side it too at end of your "AddHeader" lines in the server side file:


<% Response.AddHeader "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true" %>



If not solve keep it and change the "*" to localhost as:


<% Response.AddHeader "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost" %>



Or add port too as:


<% Response.AddHeader "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000" %>



